# Why is Mockito boolean stub being ignored

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method that checks a condition and does some work.

```
public void doSomeWork(){
   if(!UtilityClass.someCondition()){
       context.getmeSomething();
   }
}
```

My test looks like this.

```
@Test
public void test(){
    myClass.doSomeWork();

    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(UtilityClass.class)
    when(UtilityClass.someCondition()).thenReturn(false);

    verify(mContext, times(1)).getmeSomething();
}
```

The problem is the stub is simply ignored. The test passes regardless of the stub result. By the same token, never verification on fails and I get Never wanted at the test but wanted at my class under test from Mockito. My question is why the boolean stub being ignored?

Update
I am not sure if it is significant with my original question, but the Utility class is included in the prepare for test and has mockStatic call in setUp.

Comment: You have to put the when statement before calling the function

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but that same stub causes mockito to throw "Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock".

Comment: Are you correctly mocking the context into myClass? Maybe you are checking interactions with mocked Context but you are never setting the mocked context to be the one used in MyClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like GabrielJoerg said the stubbing should happen first before the method call. But the real issue here is that when stubbing, you should avoid calling verifyStatic. Here is what worked for me.

```
@Test
public void test(){
    when(UtilityClass.someCondition()).thenReturn(false);

    myClass.doSomeWork();

    verify(mContext, times(1)).getmeSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ordering of your statements!

1. Register your mocks and behaviour of it.
2. Call the method
3. Verify

EDIT:
you should also make sure, that UtilityClass is a mock. You can't stub actual classes, just mocks of them.

```
@Rule
public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Mock
private UtilityClass utilityClassMock;

private MyClass myClass;

@Before
public void beforeEachTest() {
    myClass = new MyClass(utilityClassMock);
}


@Test
public void test(){
    when(utilityClassMock.someCondition).thenReturn(false); 

    myClass.doSomeWork();

    verify(mContext, times(1)).getmeSomething();
}
```

Comment: You might also want to point out that doing the `verifyStatic` is pointless, if there is no actual verifcation statement afterwards. And you're missing the brackets `()` on someCondition (as well as the static mocking of the `UtilityClass`).